# How to get all elements into list or string with Selenium using C#?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried using WebElement (and IWebElement) and string lists, but I keep getting errors. How can I get a list or strings of all the elements text by classname? I have all Selenium references. Do I need some java.util dll?

Should I implement a foreach loop?

```
IList<IWebElement> all = new IList<IWebElement>();
all = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comments")).Text;
```

Error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Error: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get all of the element text like this:

```
IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comments"));

String[] allText = new String[all.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (IWebElement element in all)
{
    allText[i++] = element.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Although you've accepted an answer, it can be condensed using LINQ:

```
List<string> elementTexts = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comments")).Select(iw => iw.Text);
```

Comment: +1, LINQ is clearer, more readable and maintainable than the accepted answer.

Comment: @arran I tried this recently, and found that I needed to structure it like this:  `List<string> elementTexts = new List<string>(driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comments")).Select(iw => iw.Text));` due to a conversion issue.

Comment: I don't have an IDE to hand, but yeah, most likely, since what comes back is a `ReadOnlyCollection`. You could either just specify it as an `IEnumerable`, (since `ReadOnlyCollection` implements `IEnumerable`) so `IEnumerable<string> texts = driver.FindElements....` or `ToList()` at the end.... `List<string> texts = driver.FindElements(.....).ToList()` or do your method. Good spot. @Richard

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't create an instead of `IList<T>`, you have to create an instance of class that implements the interface, e.g. `List<T>`:

   ```
   IList<IWebElement> all = new List<IWebElement>();
   ```
2. However, you need `.Text` of each `IWebElement`, so your list should probably be `List<string>`:

   ```
   IList<string> all = new List<string>();
   ```
3. Use `foreach` to add items into your list:

   ```
   foreach(var element in driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("comments"));
   {
       all.Add(element.Text);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too, and it parses through the menu list and gets the list text.

```
IWebElement menuOptions;
menuOptions = _browserInstance.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']/ul[2]/li[3]"));
IList<IWebElement> list = menuOptions.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

//// get the column headers
char[] character = "\r\n".ToCharArray();
string[] Split = menuOptions.Text.Split(character);

for (int i = 0; i < Split.Length; i++)
{
    if (Split[i] != "")
    {
        _log.LogEntry("INFO", "column Text", true,
                Split + " Text matches the expected:" + Split[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this form

```
    public List<string> GetValidations()
    {
        IList<IWebElement> elementList = _webDriver.FindElements(By.Id("validationList")); // note the FindElements, plural.
        List<string> validations = new List<string>();
        foreach (IWebElement element in elementList)
        {
            validations.Add(element.ToString());
        }
        return validations;
    }
```