# Collect all the div id inside the table webdriver using c#

Tags: c#, selenium

```html
<table id="tblRenewalAgent" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-row">
<div id="trStatus" style="">
<div id="trFees" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trFees1" class="form-row ctrl-column" style="">
<div id="trFilingReceipt" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trComments" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trContact" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trEmail" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trPhone" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trCell" class="form-row" style="">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-row ctrl-column">
<div id="trAmountPaid">
<div id="trBalanceDue" class="form-row">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this is my html code.
i want to collect all div id's store it in an array string. 
how can i do it? please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find all `div` elements (having an `id` attribute) inside the `table` with `id="tblRenewalAgent"` and use `GetAttribute` to get id attribute values.

If you would use [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23591992/771848):

```
IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table#tblRenewalAgent div[id]"));
List<string> ids = all.Select(iw => iw.GetAttribute("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all div id's use can use below xpath:

```
By.xpath("//table[@id='tblRenewalAgent']/tr[1]/td[1]");
```

Store all the list of div element id's in a list. Use below code:

```
IList<IWebElement> allDivElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tblRenewalAgent']/tr[1]/td[1]"));
for(int i=0; i < allDivElements.size(); i++){
     //here the print statement will print the value of each div tag element
     print("Value of ID= "+allDivElements.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it

```
IList<IWebElement> divCollection = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tblRenewalAgent")).FindElements(By.TagName("div"));
```